# Login index form is not working with login.php if i use header() function

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

I am beginner in php.
I am trying to make a login form(index1.php).
It works fine if i redirect it to login.php using "action" attribute in form tag.
But i also want some validations on same index form.So, i am redirecting it to "login.php" using header function and not in "action" attribute.

No matter if i enter correct username and password or not, it is giving me errors of invalid variables '$username' and '$password' while executing the last else too of login.php(//that user doesnt exist).
Please help me in knowing whats wrong with my code and what should i do to make it run with login.php?

Here is the code of index1.php

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head><br>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body style="font-family: verdana, sans-serif;";>   
<hr />
<div style="width: 77%; height: 300px; padding: 30px; border: 5px solid #e3e3e3; background-color: #F8F8F8 ; color: #000; margin: 100px;" align="center">
 <br>
<?php

 $username=$password="";
 $Err="";

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "POST")
 {  

     $valid = true;

     if ((empty($_POST["username"])) || (empty($_POST["password"])))
    {
      $Err = "Please Enter your username and password";
      $valid = false; 
    }

   else 
    {

      $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
      $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
    }


   if($valid)
   { 
     header("location:login.php");
   }


 } 

 function test_input($data) 
{
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}

?>

 <span class="error"><?php echo $Err; ?></span>
 <h2>Login</h2>
 <form action="menubar.php?page=index1" method="post">
      <font size="3">Username:<input type="text" name="username" style="padding: 4px;"/><p>
      Password: <input type="password" name="password" style="padding: 4px;"/><p>
                 <input type="submit" value="Login" style="padding: 4px; width: 5em; height: 1.9em;"/></font>
    </form>
     <h5> No Account?<a href="menubar.php?page=register">Register!</a></h5>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the code of login.php.

```
<?php

session_start();

$username=$_POST["username"];
$password=$_POST["password"];
$message[]="Fill up both username and password";

    $connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Couldnt connect to Database");
    mysql_select_db("login") or die("Couldnt find Database");
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($numrows!==0)//username exists in database
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            $dbusername = $row['username'];
            $dbpassword = $row['password'];
        }
        if($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword)//valid username and password
        {

            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
           header("Location: menubar.php?page=home");
        }
        else//incorrect password or username
        die("incorrect password or username");

    }
    else//that user doesnt exit
    die("that user doesnt exit");//


?>
```

Okay, Now i used 'sqli' instead

Here is that updated login.php code

```
<?php

session_start();

$username=$_POST["username"];
$password=$_POST["password"];
$message[]="Fill up both username and password";

    $connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Couldnt connect to Database");
    mysqli_select_db($connect,'login') or die("Couldnt find Database");
    $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if($numrows!==0)//username exists in database
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            $dbusername = $row['username'];
            $dbpassword = $row['password'];
        }
        if($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword)//valid username and password
        {

            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
           header("Location: menubar.php?page=home");
        }
        else//incorrect password or username
        die("incorrect password or username");

    }
    else//that user doesnt exit
    die("that user doesnt exit");//


?>
```

Now after updating i am not getting errors of invalid variables .
But it still not going on correctly.No matter whether i enter correct username and password or not, it is executing the innermost if i.e. (//valid username and password)

Thanks....

Comment: still using mysql_connect? why? can you test your query in database?

Comment: First of all, there are a couple of major problem in your code: `mysql_` syntax is obsolete and not safe: please use [pdo](http://www.php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead; then is very unsafe store passwords without hashing-it: take a look at built-in [password_hash](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). BTW, you have checked some error? I think the problem is in the SQL query, if the result if "that user doesnt exit". Try the query through phpMyAdmin to check if it is correct.

Comment: Thank you for replying guys,
I tested the query in phpmyadmin, it is working fine.
I dont understand why it is showing errors of invalid variables i.e. $username and $password

Comment: Ok guys as you said i used 'mysqli' instead but now,no matter whether i enter correct username and password or not, it is executing the innermost if i.e(//valid username and password).
Good thing is that it stops giving errors of invalid variables.

Comment: @Sachin can you please update your post using your current code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As already suggested, put all your PHP code before any HTML output
2. You are not passing the POST variables with the header() function, you can either use sessions or POST to the same page

So your code would be something like this

```
<?php

 $username=$password="";
 $Err="";

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "POST")
 {  

     $valid = true;

     if ((empty($_POST["username"])) || (empty($_POST["password"])))
    {
      $Err = "Please Enter your username and password";
      $valid = false; 
    }

   else 
    {

      $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
      $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
    }


   if($valid)
   { 
     include("login.php");
   }


 } 

 function test_input($data) 
{
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}

?>

  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head><br>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body style="font-family: verdana, sans-serif;";>   
<hr />
<div style="width: 77%; height: 300px; padding: 30px; border: 5px solid #e3e3e3; background-color: #F8F8F8 ; color: #000; margin: 100px;" align="center">
 <br>

 <span class="error"><?php echo $Err; ?></span>
 <h2>Login</h2>
 <form action="menubar.php?page=index1" method="post">
      <font size="3">Username:<input type="text" name="username" style="padding: 4px;"/><p>
      Password: <input type="password" name="password" style="padding: 4px;"/><p>
                 <input type="submit" value="Login" style="padding: 4px; width: 5em; height: 1.9em;"/></font>
    </form>
     <h5> No Account?<a href="menubar.php?page=register">Register!</a></h5>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alot,
But i also had to again revert back changes of 'sqli' to 'sql'.

sqli was giving some errors, but i think i can solve them and make it work with sqli too.
Thank you.. :)

Comment: The login.php file was not causing the error, so even if mysql is deprecated it did not cause the issue.

Comment: Yeah you are right bro.,, Your code worked great. Its just that i cant tick more than 1 answer. I got more than 1 answers and all of them worked fine and are simple. I appreciated everybody's help . Thanks

Comment: Usually you choose the correct answer that comes first (and that was not edited after other answers)
Anyway never mind, glad you solved :)

Answer (score 1):

It is very important to note that you should have not sent any output to the client before setting the header-

`header("Location: menubar.php?page=home");//or login.php`

So before sending any data validate your data and set the header, if invalid data else send the normal data.

**Update: Below is complete tested code**

index1.php

```
<?php session_start();?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head><br>
<style>
    .error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body style="font-family: verdana, sans-serif;";>   
<hr />
<div style="width: 77%; height: 300px; padding: 30px; border: 5px solid #e3e3e3; background-color: #F8F8F8 ; color: #000; margin: 100px;" align="center">
 <br>
 <?php if(isset($_SESSION['message'])){ echo  "<span class='error'>".$_SESSION['message']."</span>"; $_SESSION['message']=null;}?>
 <h2>Login</h2>
 <form action="login.php" method="post">
         <font size="3">Username:<input type="text" name="username" style="padding: 4px;"/><p>
  Password: <input type="password" name="password" style="padding: 4px;"/><p>
             <input type="submit" value="Login" style="padding: 4px; width: 5em; height: 1.9em;"/></font>
</form>
 <h5> No Account?<a href="menubar.php?page=register">Register!</a></h5>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

login.php

```
<?php

session_start();
$username=$password="";
$Err="";

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "POST")
 {
    $valid = true;
 if ((empty($_POST["username"])) || (empty($_POST["password"])))
{
  $Err = "Please Enter your username and password";
  $valid = false; 
}
else 
{

  $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
  $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
}
   if($valid) {
    $valid = false;//reset $valid value to validate for Database test

    //$username=$_POST["username"];
    //$password=$_POST["password"];
    //$message[]="Fill up both username and password";

    $connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Couldnt connect to Database");
    mysqli_select_db($connect,'login') or die("Couldnt find Database");
//Note: mysqi_query() returns results of query
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");//update here pass the $connect parameter

    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);//change here

if($numrows!==0)//username exists in database
{
    $dbusername = null;//move it up for visibility after while block
    $dbpassword = null;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))//Note here pass the result
    {
        $dbusername = $row['username'];
        $dbpassword = $row['password'];
    }
    if($username == $dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword)//valid username and password
    {

        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
       header("Location: menubar.php?page=home");//the landing page
       die();
    }
    else{
        //incorrect password or username
        $Err = "incorrect password or username";
        $valid = false;
    }

}
else {
    //that user doesnt exit
    $Err = "that user doesnt exit";
    $valid = false;
}   
 //header("location:index.php");
}   
if(!$valid) {
    $_SESSION['message'] = $Err;//Put the message in $_SESSION variable
    header("location:index1.php");
}
 }
function test_input($data) 
{
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>
```

menubar.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$page=isset($_GET["page"])?$_GET["page"]:"";
if(isset($page)) {
    header("location: ".$page.".php");
} else {
    header("location: 404.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: LoL i am noob bro.I didnt understand your point. 
Thats too much hifi language you used.

Could you please write the code and tell me which line do i need to replace?I can only understand it better if i used it practically.
Thank you

Comment: Hope this helps in complete flow.

Comment: In your last code you were redirecting to `login.php` from `menubar.php` page and trying to access the data in `login.php` with `$_POST['username']`. It is not valid. You can access the `$_POST['username']` only if data is sent from client and the form method is `post`. Otherwise you have to get parameters using `$_GET['username']` or `$_REQUEST['username']` if the data is part of the `URL`. Example: `/login.php?username=Kamal&password=kamal`. I hope you understand this.

Comment: Thanks alot bro,
I tried your code, it  also worked fine .
I am really very grateful for you people efforts.
I learnt alot today, because of you people.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is in `login.php`, `$_POST["username"]` and `$_POST["password"]` was never been set so it the best thing you could do is not to use `header` and just use `require_once`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head><br>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body style="font-family: verdana, sans-serif;";>   
<hr />
<div style="width: 77%; height: 300px; padding: 30px; border: 5px solid #e3e3e3; background-color: #F8F8F8 ; color: #000; margin: 100px;" align="center">
 <br>
<?php

 $username=$password="";
 $Err="";

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "POST"){  

     $valid = true;

     if ((empty($_POST["username"])) || (empty($_POST["password"]))){

      $Err = "Please Enter your username and password";
      $valid = false; 

    }else{

      $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
      $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);

    }


   if($valid)
   { 
     require_once('login.php');
   }


} 

 function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}

?>

 <span class="error"><?php echo $Err; ?></span>
 <h2>Login</h2>
 <form action="menubar.php?page=index1" method="post">
      <font size="3">Username:<input type="text" name="username" style="padding: 4px;"/><p>
      Password: <input type="password" name="password" style="padding: 4px;"/><p>
                 <input type="submit" value="Login" style="padding: 4px; width: 5em; height: 1.9em;"/></font>
    </form>
     <h5> No Account?<a href="menubar.php?page=register">Register!</a></h5>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, I tried it, it is working fine. Thanks again..
Appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have an output:

```
?>
<?php
```

results in blank line output.

header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP

Combine all your PHP codes and make sure you don't have any spaces at the beginning of the file.

also after `header('location: index.php');` add `exit();` if you have any other scripts bellow.

Also move your redirect header after the last if.

Comment: you can use obstart();before header();